# What conditions will bound a position: fixed element to its parent's box?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a backdrop for a menu that will be used to detect if the user has clicked somewhere other than on the menu and close the menu.

For some reason despite setting

```
.menu-backdrop {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

The backdrop won't stretch beyond one of the parent divs.

I've distilled the webpage to something simple and stuck it here http://codepen.io/ben_irule/pen/LZWwjL?editors=1100

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .app-layout {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .layout {
        height: calc(100% - 35px);
        display: block;
    }

    footer {
        height: 35px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .content {
        position: relative;

        /* attribute of doom*/
        transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);

        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: 320px;
        margin-right: 280px;
    }

    .menu-backdrop {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div  class="app-layout">
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="menu-backdrop"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've noted one transform attribute that when disabled stops the parent div from being problematic.  However when I disable the equivalent attribute in the full blown app it does not resolve the issue.

**I'm interested in understanding what conditions will result in a fixed position element being bound by a parent div.**

I've been searching the web all morning but haven't found anything resembling my current issue.

Comment: Your example is small enough that I would recommend putting it into a snippet so it can be seen in your question.

Comment: You might be interested in using the [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: funny behavior indeed. If you mean to set in fixed position your element you may take it out its parent (where transform comes in the way) to avoid run in this unexpected behavior. (can't cure ?, avoid it ! )

Answer (score 1):

```
.content {
  position: relative;

  /* attribute of doom*/
  transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);

  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-right: 280px;
}
```

Margin left and margin right is what stopping you to stretch beyond what it is now. Try reducing it.

---

Here is a better way of doing it. See if this solves your problem. Since you have a specific numbered margin, add those to menu-backdrop.

```
 .menu-backdrop {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: -320px;
      margin-right: -280px;
      margin-bottom: -32px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Decreasing the margins to Zero resolves the issue horizontally but it doesn't take care of the footer.  Unfortunately on the actual page I need to keep the margins in place.  Do you know why the parent element is acting as a boundary in the first place?

Comment: menu-backdrop covering footer as well might not be possible because the maximum height layout class can go is the height you defined **height: calc(100% - 35px);**. I think you might have to play with position attribute of footer and also add an additional 35px height to menu-backdrop to make it visible over footer.
I am not sure on why parent acts as boundary. Child width can overflow parent if you change margin to padding in .content class. But you need to check how this change affects the page on different devices. Why do you need margin for?Plan to load this page on different devices?

Answer (score 0):

This will pull the backdrop beyond the width of the containing div. A negative margin usually does the job:

```
.menu-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left:-30px;
  margin-right:-30px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Negative margins do expand it. I set a massive z-index too and for some reason the footer and sidenavs still cover up the backdrop. It still seems to be bound by the parent div. Do you know why the parent element is acting as a boundary in the first place?

Comment: The parent div had no width set, so it's auto by default. The margin-left && right take away from the automatic width. The fixed position usually only keeps it in the same place for scrolling up/down (maybe left/right, never actually tried that). I think if a div is nested, no matter what z-index is put on it, it wont overtake or overlap on any divs higher up the tree from itself

Comment: But If I disable the transform attribute on the parent div it still doesn't have a width yet it no longer binds the child divs size.

Comment: Oh, because the margin on either side is pushing it away from the left and right. So whatever div that doesn't have a size larger than 100% will fit inside the parent

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps changing your layout to this:

```
<body>
  <div class="app-layout">
    <div class="layout">
      <div class="menu-backdrop"></div>
      <div class="content">
        Need to stretch more!!
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

and styling similar to:

```
.menu-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  max-width:750px;
  margin:auto;

  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```